# Algorithm: Find repetitive groups in 2D-point distribution

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching, mathematical-optimization, spatial

I am currently working on an interesting project looking for finding repeating groups in a 2D point distribution. Each group consists of four points whose position with respect to each other is constrained by some boundary conditions. I am trying to find an automated group finder and group matcher.

The point data consists of an 2D array. We have N point.

```
points = array[N,2]
```

Each group ("*tool*") is composed of four points (a,b,c,d) that sit on the edges of a square (length=L), but whose position can be changed by a small amount (displacement=D). Here the values are L=1.000, D=0.150.

[image: Group matching pattern - Green: Base length L, Black: Movement radius]

At the moment my current approach is the following:

1. Load all the point data (points)
2. Iterate for every point *p* in points
3. Search all points which are in inside the four quadrats a,b,c,d (relative to point *p*)
4. For every combination *q* of all the found points (a,b,c,d)
5. Check if combination *q* is feasible (distance *dist* between points: L-D < *dist* < L+D)
6. Store combination *q* in toolList *TL*

After the parsing of the point data I try to find the tools which are most used. The toolList *TL* is an 8-dimensional space. But because for every step 4 there are a lot of combination, this tool-space is quite cluttered.

Do you have any other idea for a better approach ?

Appended you can find some example data:
[image: Example data]

---

Example data points (2 combinations with 10 repetitions each)

```
points =[[0.016,0.920],[0.995,1.080],[0.041,-0.069],[0.957,0.039],[1.496,1.081],[2.582,0.932],[1.536,0.015],[2.541,0.095],[0.516,1.420],[1.495,1.580],[0.541,0.431],[1.457,0.539],[1.996,1.581],[3.082,1.432],[2.036,0.515],[3.041,0.595],[1.016,1.920],[1.995,2.080],[1.041,0.931],[1.957,1.039],[2.496,2.081],[3.582,1.932],[2.536,1.015],[3.541,1.095],[1.516,2.420],[2.495,2.580],[1.541,1.431],[2.457,1.539],[2.996,2.581],[4.082,2.432],[3.036,1.515],[4.041,1.595],[2.016,2.920],[2.995,3.080],[2.041,1.931],[2.957,2.039],[3.496,3.081],[4.582,2.932],[3.536,2.015],[4.541,2.095],[2.516,3.420],[3.495,3.580],[2.541,2.431],[3.457,2.539],[3.996,3.581],[5.082,3.432],[4.036,2.515],[5.041,2.595],[3.016,3.920],[3.995,4.080],[3.041,2.931],[3.957,3.039],[4.496,4.081],[5.582,3.932],[4.536,3.015],[5.541,3.095],[3.516,4.420],[4.495,4.580],[3.541,3.431],[4.457,3.539],[4.996,4.581],[6.082,4.432],[5.036,3.515],[6.041,3.595],[4.016,4.920],[4.995,5.080],[4.041,3.931],[4.957,4.039],[5.496,5.081],[6.582,4.932],[5.536,4.015],[6.541,4.095],[4.516,5.420],[5.495,5.580],[4.541,4.431],[5.457,4.539],[5.996,5.581],[7.082,5.432],[6.036,4.515],[7.041,4.595]]
```

Comment: x, y coords for example data?

Comment: And example l, D.

Comment: You need to give feedback...

Answer (score 0):

assuming `l >> d` I put the points on a d-sized grid and look for the `l // d` squares then convert back to the original points.
Note that more than one point can map to the same d-grid point so the answer is given as a list lists representing squares. squares are four lists of corner-points for one square where any corner may be represented by more than one point in the d-neighbourhood.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict


l = 205     # Square side
d = 25      # point +/- delta

# Up to max_points distinct integer points in range 0..r_max
r_max = 1_750
max_points = 1_000
points_x = random.sample(range(r_max), max_points)
points_y = random.sample(range(r_max), max_points)
points = list(set(zip(points_x, points_y)))


dgrid_2_points = defaultdict(list)  # Move points to d-sized grid
for x, y in points:
    dgrid_2_points[(x // d, y // d)].append((x, y))

d_l = l // d  # Square side in d-grids

d_points_set = set(dgrid_2_points)      # gridded points to check
d_points = sorted(d_points_set)         # order for checking

d_found = []            # Squares found on d-grid
for a in d_points:
    x, y = a
    b, c, d = (x, y+d_l), (x+d_l, y+d_l), (x+d_l, y)
    if all(p in d_points_set for p in (b, c, d)):
        d_found.append((a, b, c, d))
    d_points_set.remove(a)


found = [[dgrid_2_points[d_pt] for d_pt in d_square]
         for d_square in d_found]

"""
# EXAMPLE VALUE

found = \
[[[(236, 823), (240, 819)], [(239, 1018)], [(446, 1005)], [(425, 824)]],
 [[(540, 282)], [(534, 496)], [(726, 491)], [(733, 283)]],
 [[(586, 172)], [(585, 355)], [(794, 363)], [(797, 174)]],
 [[(755, 67)], [(763, 257)], [(972, 252)], [(958, 66)]],
 [[(924, 197)], [(912, 382)], [(1124, 393), (1104, 381)], [(1115, 181)]],
 [[(1375, 28)], [(1386, 245)], [(1581, 246)], [(1586, 43)]]]

"""
```

The example shows it found six squares. The first square found has any of the following two points as one corner:  `[(236, 823), (240, 819)]` its other three corners are single points.

**Note**: There could be an error where I should have used a d/2 grid rather than the d-grid I did use.  You need to check. In that case just substitute half the original d value and assume you are reporting on d.

## WITH YOUR EXAMPLE POINTS

You've now given a set of example points.

- Running with your points, an `l` of 1 and a `d` of .15 I find **no**
  squares.
- Multiplying `d` by two I then find **six squares**, with some of the corners occupied by multiple points.

```
# YOUR EXAMPLE

l = 1.0
d = 0.15
points = ...

found = [] # Nothing

# Change d

d = 0.15 * 2

found = [
 [[(0.995, 1.08), (1.041, 0.931)], [(1.016, 1.92)], [(1.995, 2.08), (2.041, 1.931)], [(1.957, 1.039)]].
 [[(2.582, 0.932), (2.536, 1.015)], [(2.496, 2.081)], [(3.582, 1.932), (3.536, 2.015)], [(3.541, 1.095)]].
 [[(2.495, 2.58), (2.541, 2.431)], [(2.516, 3.42)], [(3.495, 3.58), (3.541, 3.431)], [(3.457, 2.539)]].
 [[(4.082, 2.432), (4.036, 2.515)], [(3.996, 3.581)], [(5.082, 3.432), (5.036, 3.515)], [(5.041, 2.595)]].
 [[(3.995, 4.08), (4.041, 3.931)], [(4.016, 4.92)], [(4.995, 5.08)], [(4.957, 4.039)]].
 [[(5.582, 3.932), (5.536, 4.015)], [(5.496, 5.081)], [(6.582, 4.932)], [(6.541, 4.095)]].]
```

Is this what you were expecting?

### Graph

The red is the found square the blue extends +/- half d to show points captured for corners.

[image: Graph of example points and found squares]